# Excel 2007: finding duplicates ACROSS multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel 2010 conditional formatting: selectively highlighting duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/459541/excel-2010-conditional-formatting-selectively-highlighting-duplicates)

First of all, this is basically a cut-and-paste of [another question](https://superuser.com/q/459541/76571) regarding Excel 2010. When I commented on that post, it wouldn't post, so I am trying a whole new question thread.

I'm using Excel 2007 and would like to know if there's any way I can choose conditional formatting to highlight only instances of duplicates when it's found in ALL the columns I chose?

For instance, I have six columns of data, with duplicates in them, but I only want those duplicates to be highlighted if they appear in ALL SIX columns.

E.g.

```
A        B        C        D        E        F
Dog      Cat      Bird     Platypus Otter    Lion
Cat      Platypus Zebra    Bird     Lion     Ostrich
Fish     Panda    Giraffe  Dog      Platypus Platypus
Horse    Chicken  Platypus Zebra    Giraffe  Dog
Platypus Dog      Panda    Horse    Zebra    Snake
```

Only "Platypus" appears in all six columns, but "Dog", "Cat", "Horse", etc all have one or more duplicates, which will usually end up being highlighted. If I can find a solution that will allow me to have the flexibility of choosing to highlight instances of duplicates in 5 out of 6 columns, 4 out of 6 columns, 3 out of 6 columns, etc, that'd be even better!

Note that the data is not arranged nicely in a row, so that I couldn't use "Countif" across rows to see how many times "dog" appeared in Column A-L on a specific row (i.e. "dog" could appear anywhere in the columns, not necessarily on the same row).

I tried using a =AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,A>1,.........) scheme, but it tells me that I cannot use "unions, intersections, or arrays constants for Conditional Formatting criteria."

If anyone has any tips on this, I'd really appreciate it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be a NESTED IF and COUNT. In fact you do not even have to provide the number of columns, as long as there is a non-blank value, you can go through several IF NOT ELSE logic control to highlight 5, 4, 3, 2, columns and their values.

If you ask this question on http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/ , you might get a working script, as there people only devote time to Excel/VBS.

Hope this helps you.