# Formatting a column based on another columns cell TEXT (not value) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel 2010 conditional formatting: selectively highlighting duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/459541/excel-2010-conditional-formatting-selectively-highlighting-duplicates)

I have dates that are running off a formula in that column based on information it's collecting from other worksheets.  I have another column that lists text answers based on a different formula that that column is running.

It is a customer list that  runs with names going down page and multiple columns of information for each client running across page

What I want to do is:

**If column `J` says `paid` then turn column `M` - same row - a color or border or something.**

I will repeat this formula for the various things that `J` can say, I just can't figure out how to make conditional formatting read `J` to change `M`.

To complicate things, in addition to the formula running to collect the date in column `M`, there is also a conditional format set up for `M` that changes the color of the cells after a certain date.  I want to be able to keep that formula, in addition to the one that you are assisting with.  I will use highlighting, or something different to avoid any conflicts.

Answer (score 9):

- Select column M. Check which cell is highlighted (let's assume
  M1)
- Conditional Formatting \ New Rule
- Use a formula to determine which cells to format
- Type in the following formula `=J1="paid"` (using the highlighted
  cell's row number - remember M1)
- Choose your formatting, then validate.
- Repeat as needed for the other conditions and formats.
- for your other condition (see comment) `=and(or(j1="renew",j1="-"),M1>=today()+1)`

Comment: Another hint: If you want the condition to format several cells on the same row, select them all and use the formula `=$J1="paid"` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm...now, for the second part...  if column j="renew" or "-" AND date in column M is 4 days or more behind todays date, than higlight or change color or whatever in M!

Comment: updated the answer accordingly.