# How to do conditional formatting based on several criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a column based on another columns cell TEXT (not value) in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/482615/formatting-a-column-based-on-another-columns-cell-text-not-value-in-excel)

How can I implement the following as an Excel formula?

If column j="renew" or "-" AND the date in column M is 4 days or more behind today's date,
then higlight or change color or whatever in column M.

Comment: It seems you've asked this [here](http://superuser.com/questions/482615/formatting-a-column-based-on-another-columns-cell-text-not-value-in-excel#comment572576_482627) already?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule:

```
=AND(OR(J1="renew", J1="-"),TODAY()-M1>4)
```

I don't know if the setup is the same in Excel 2007, but in Excel 2010, it looks like this:
[image: conditional formatting dialog]

You can access the dialog through selecting tab **Home**, menu **Conditional formatting**, entry **New rule...**.
Then you can choose the format you want (here, a red background), and click **OK**.

Here's the result:

[image]