# How do I format cells in one column based off cells in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

So I found some similar questions to this already answered here, but they don't go deep enough for what I want to do, and was hoping to find some more help.

At a high level I want to format some cells in column A with a specific value to be a certain color if a cell in column L is populated with something.  Doesn't matter what it is, though in this particular instance it will be a date, however in the future it could be text, or a number etc.  Additionally, if the cell in column L is empty, but the cell in column A has that specific text I want it to be formatted with a different color combo so I can tell that I need to check up on the status of the data in the cell.

Ideally, and really the only thing I have time for (this particular sheet has several thousand rows of data) would be to be able to set this up en masse.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well I've found and tried a few things, which can be found [here](http://superuser.com/questions/482615/formatting-a-column-based-on-another-columns-cell-text-not-value-in-excel?rq=1), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/459541/excel-2010-conditional-formatting-selectively-highlighting-duplicates), and [here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-41481-conditional-formating-apply-on-more-cells) but I'm not really sure how to take all that and use it to get the results I desire.

Comment: OK. What do you mean by *"Additionally, if the cell in column L is empty, but the cell in column A has that specific text I want it to be formatted with a different color combo so I can tell that I need to check up on the status of the data in the cell"*?

Comment: So cells in column A will have a few different texts in them, things like "Flag Set", "Reset", "Defer", "User Changed".  The corresponding cells in column L will either be blank, OR have a date in them of when an action was taken.  For this example, I would like cells in A with "Flag Set" to be a Green color combo when there is a date in the corresponding L column.  So if A1 has "Flag Set" and L1 has a date, then A1 would be green fill, green text.  If A1 had "Flag set but L1 was empty, A1 would be a different color, easily alerting me I need to check in on that account for an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you can accomplish this with two conditional format rules which use formulas. You didn't state what version you are using, so you will have to use whatever method you need.

The first rule will use the following formula: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($L1)), $A1="Flag set")` This checks to see that `L` is NOT blank AND `A1="Flag set"`. If both are met, it formats `A` accordingly.

The second formula will be: `=AND(ISBLANK($L1), $A1="Flag set")`. This checks to see if `L` is blank and if `A` contains certain text. If both are TRUE, then it formats `A` accordingly.

For both rules, select your formatting and apply them to `$A:$A` so they will be applied to all rows in column `A`.

[image]

Comment: Can I also apply the specific text to the first statement?

Comment: Sure. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select cell `A1` (if you don't, these directions will not work due to the relative reference you create in step #3...which is the *key* to being able to apply these conditions to all the entire worksheet)
2. Create a new Conditional Formatting rule of the **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** type
3. In the **Format values where this formula is true:** text box, enter something like the following that describes the condition you're testing for.  Note the `$` are provided for the column references but **not** the row references.  This causes the formula to test the values in columns `A` and `L` where the row numbers are the same:

   ```
   =$A1<>$L1
   ```
4. Configure the **Format** that should be applied to the cell in column `A` if the conditional formula is true.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for each additional condition you which to test for.
6. If you wish to prevent any subsequent rules from being evaluated if a certain rule is found true, enable the **Stop If True** checkbox for that rule in the *Conditional Formatting Rules Manager* dialog box.  You may also re-order the rules to determine precedence of one over another.
7. Test various values in cells `A1` and `L1` until you're satisfied your rules work.  *Only then should you...*
8. Change all of the **Applies to** values for the rules to `=$A:$A`